# How to handle Stackoverflow error during Serialization from an Object to JSON in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to convert an object to JSON, below is the object

```
 @Data 
    public class OraganisationStructures{
         @Autowired 
        private    OrganisationProperties organisationProperties;
         ....
         ...

     }
```

I get the below exception and error. How do I handle this. This error is stopping my log appenders where the logs are getting vanished due to this error.

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap["  "]->com.java.sample.OraganisationStructures$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6c9f7932["organisationProperties"]->com.java.sample.OraganisationStructures$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$99c7d84b["$$beanFactory"]->org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory["singletonObjects"]at  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:706)
at  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
at  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704)
at  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690)
at  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `@JsonIgnore` to break the Infinite recursion in case you are with ignoring one side of mapping. Otherwise use `@JsonManagedReference`, `@JsonBackReference` for bi directional mapping.

Comment: The class is already available in my application and I cannot change it. Is there anyway I can configure it glblly through an ObjectMapper